# Newtype as generic parameter in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust

Suppose I have the following newtype:

```
pub struct Num(pub i32);
```

Now, I have a function which accepts an optional `Num`:

```
pub fn calc(nu: Option<Num>) -> i32 {
    let real_nu = match nu { // extract the value inside Num
        Some(nu) => nu.0,
        None     => -1
    };
    // performs lots of complicated calculations...
    real_nu * 1234
}
```

What I want to write is a generic `extract` function like the one below (which won't compile):

```
// T here would be "Num" newtype
// R would be "i32", which is wrapped by "Num"

pub fn extract<T, R>(val: Option<T>) -> R {
    match val {
        Some(val) => val.0, // return inner number
        None      => -1 as R
    }
}
```

So that I can bypass the `match` inside my calc function:

```
pub fn calc(nu: Option<Num>) -> i32 {
    // do a lot of complicated calculations...
    extract(nu) * 1234 // automatically extract i32 or -1
}
```

How can I write `extract`?

**Motivation:** in the program I'm writing, there are several newtypes like `Num`, and they wrap `i8`, `i16` and `i32`. And there are many different `calc` functions. It's getting very repetitive to write all these `match`es at the begining of each `calc` function.

Comment: Isn't it less than ideal that `calc` would return `-1234`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth The `-1` is just an example, the real number will probably be a [rational number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number).

Comment: @Rodrigo: What exactly is the problem with `extract`? In which way should it be generic? (If it is working on `Num` and `Num` always wraps `i32`, where does it need to be generic?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I figured out a much easier and elegant way to accomplish this. First, implement `Default` trait for my newtype:

```
use std::default::Default;

pub struct Num(pub i32);

impl Default for Num {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self(-1)
    }
}
```

And then, when needed, just use `unwrap_or_default` accessing first newtype tuple element:

```
pub fn calc(nu: Option<Num>) -> i32 {
    // do a lot of complicated calculations...
    nu.unwrap_or_default().0 * 1234
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Such a function would generally be unsafe since the internals might be private (and hence have restricted access). For example, suppose we have a newtype and implement `Drop` for it.

```
struct NewType(String);

impl Drop for NewType {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("{}", self.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = NewType("abc".to_string());
    let y = Some(x);

    // this causes a compiler error
    // let s = match y {
    //     Some(s) => s.0,
    //     None => panic!(),
    // };
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=91f7d29aa8f1411c7cf263a2d76d88a5)

If your function worked, you'd be able to move the inner string out of the newtype. Then when the struct is dropped, it's able to access invalid memory.

Nonetheless, you can write a macro that implements something along those lines. If you try to use the macro on something implementing `Drop`, the compiler will complain, but otherwise, this should work.

```
macro_rules! extract_impl {
    (struct $struct_name: ident($type_name: ty);) => {
        struct $struct_name($type_name);
        impl $struct_name {
            fn extract(item: Option<Self>) -> $type_name {
                match item {
                    Some(item) => item.0,
                    None => panic!(), // not sure what you want here
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

extract_impl! {
    struct Num(i32);
}

impl Num {
    fn other_fun(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let x = Num(5);
    println!("{}", Num::extract(Some(x)));
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5d07e096e541effdb14f0e58c25044df)

Having an `impl` block in the output of the macro doesn't cause any problems since you can have as many `impl` blocks for a single type as you need (in the original module).

A better API would be to have `extract` return an option, rather than some meaningless value or panicking. Then the any error can easily be handled by the caller.

```
macro_rules! extract_impl {
    (struct $struct_name: ident($type_name: ty);) => {
        struct $struct_name($type_name);
        impl $struct_name {
            fn extract(item: Option<Self>) -> Option<$type_name> {
                item.map(|item| item.0)
            }
        }
    };
}

extract_impl! {
    struct Num(i32);
}

impl Num {
    fn other_fun(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let x = Num(5);
    println!("{:?}", Num::extract(Some(x)));
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=168c64e171acafa5d29c24a812464f20)

Answer (score 1):

There are two main missing pieces here:

1. You need to abstract the structure of `Num`, providing a way to extract the inner value without knowing the outer type.
2. You need to constrain `R` to have number-like properties, so that you can express the idea of `-1` for it.

The first can be solved by implementing `Deref` for `Num` and then using it as a trait bound. This will let you access the "inner" value. There are also other traits that have similar capabilities, but `Deref` is likely the one you want here:

The second can be solved by implementing the `One` trait imported from the `num-traits` crate (to get the idea of a `1` value) and by implementing `std::ops::Neg` to be able to negate it to get `-1`. You will also need to require that `R` is `Copy`  or `Clone` so you can move it out of the reference.

```
use num_traits::One;
use std::ops::{Deref, Neg}; // 0.2.8

pub struct Num(pub i32);

impl Deref for Num {
    type Target = i32;
    fn deref(&self) -> &i32 {
        &self.0
    }
}

pub fn extract<T, R>(val: Option<T>) -> R
where
    T: Deref<Target = R>,
    R: Neg<Output = R> + One + Copy,
{
    match val {
        Some(val) => *val,
        None => -R::one(),
    }
}
```

Depending on how you intend to use this, you might want to get rid of `R`, since it is always determined by `T`. As-is, the function is told by the caller the concrete types of `T` and `R`, and will make sure that `R` is `T`'s deref target. But it might be better if the caller only needs to provide `T` and let `R` be deduced from `T`.

```
pub fn extract<T>(val: Option<T>) -> T::Target
where
    T: Deref,
    <T as Deref>::Target: Neg<Output = T::Target> + One + Copy,
{
    match val {
        Some(val) => *val,
        None => -T::Target::one(),
    }
}
```